# drop all tables from sql ce database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

Is it possible to executa a command which drops all tables from sql ce database ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use information SCHEMA to generate a script:

```
select 'drop table ' || table_name || ';'
  from information_schema.tables;
```

Then run that script. You might need to run the script several times, since there is no **CASCADE** option (AFAIK) in SQLCE.

Comment: +1 - I was WAY the hell off since CE is so different from SQL Server

Comment: in case someone is still looking in 2015 - updated script could be 

select 'drop table ' + t.TABLE_SCHEMA +'.['+ t.table_name + '];' from information_schema.tables t;

Comment: @torm SQL Compact does not have schemas!

Answer (score 1):

System.IO.File.Delete and then run the requires CREATE TABLE scripts

Comment: Care to expand on that? So... delete the whole file? I just want to rebuild the database each time I run tests. Deleting the .sdf file seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can also drop database, and create it again, but it will erase all your configuration, so may not be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

1. Using [SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1) in Visual Studio, right-click on the .sdf file and select **Script Database > Script Database Schema...**
2. Save it as `CreateTables.sqlce`
3. Paste the following in a PowerShell console:

   ```
   function GenerateDropScript($DbSchemaFile)
   {
       function Reverse($inputArr)
       { 
           $arr = @($inputArr)
           [array]::Reverse($arr)
           return $arr
       }
       $TableNames = Get-Content $DbSchemaFile |
           ? { $_.StartsWith('CREATE TABLE') } |
           % { $_.Substring(14).Replace('] (', '') }
       $ReverseNames = Reverse($TableNames)

       "Generating DROP script for all tables in: `n`t$DbSchemaFile`n"

       $ReverseNames | % { "DROP TABLE [$_]; GO;" }
   }
   ```
4. Run `GenerateDropScript CreateTables.sqlce`

This will read the CREATE script and generate DROP scripts for all tables in the reverse order they are created, so you don't get any dependency errors.